Using ax.scatter to make individual markers on plot points
My code has the line below
ax1.scatter(data1[0], data1[1], marker='o',  s=20, 
            color = ['k','b','g','r','m'], 
            edgecolors= ['k','b','g','r','m'])

I would like to have the marker = ('o','d','v','^','x') for the different shapes, but this does not work.  How can I revise my code like above to give the different shapes for the different individual points.

Unlike color and edgecolors, the marker parameter is not defined as an "array-like" parameter : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html
You can loop over the data and set the symbol for each individual point:
markers = ['o','d','v','^','x']
colors= ['k','b','g','r','m']
edgecolors = ['k','b','g','r','m']

for i in range(len(data1[0])):
    ax1.scatter(data1[0][i], data1[1][i], 
            marker = markers[i],  
            s = 20, 
            c = colors[i], 
            edgecolors= edgecolors[i] )

